# ImportError: No module named html5

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms, funnelweb

I tried the following steps to setup Funnel (https://github.com/hasgeek/funnel):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hasgeek/funnel
$ cd funnel/
$ cp instance/settings-sample.py instance/settings.py
$ echo "CACHE_TYPE='simple'" >> instance/development.py
```

I then installed the following:

- Flask                         0.10.1
- Flask-Assets             0.7
- Flask-Mail                 0.6.1
- Flask-SQLAlchemy   1.0
- Flask-WTF    0.8
- pytz                           2012d
- unicodecsv                0.9.4
- icalendar                   3.4
- wtforms-html5           0.1.3
- alembic                     0.6.3
- Flask-Migrate            1.2.0
- flask-alembic             0.1

And the latest packages from:

- https://github.com/hasgeek/coaster.git
- https://github.com/hasgeek/flask-lastuser.git
- https://github.com/hasgeek/baseframe.git

Then I ran:

```
$ python manage.py db create
```

I got the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from funnel import app, models, init_for
  File "/home/safiyat/Desktop/PyDev/funnel/funnel-master/funnel/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import models, forms, views
  File "/home/safiyat/Desktop/PyDev/funnel/funnel-master/funnel/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comment import *
  File "/home/safiyat/Desktop/PyDev/funnel/funnel-master/funnel/forms/comment.py", line 6, in <module>
    import wtforms.fields.html5
ImportError: No module named html5
```

I read somewhere that html5 widgets and fields are built-in of wtforms since 1.0.5, and that they should be imported from wtforms itself. Though my installed wtforms is 1.0.2, I still get that error.
Why? Any solutions?

Comment: find html5 module path and add to your PATH variable in bashrc or bash_profile or export in other way.

Comment: There is no such module that I can find in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/ or in the fields sub-folder. Neither that adding its path will help coz it is still referring to html5 as a submodule of wtforms. I tried solving the problem using aliases but it throws up another exception in itself. The file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py on line 366, `TypeError: create_parser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parents'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I had to upgrade my wtforms to 1.0.5 using the command `pip install upgrade wtforms`.
Then downgraded my Flask-Script from 0.6.2 to 0.5.3 using `pip install Flask-Script==0.5.3`.
That worked.

Comment: May I ask why you needed to downgrade Flask-Script?

Comment: I had to downgrade after the upgrade of wtforms as without downgrading the __init__.py script of Flask-Script was throwing up exceptions saying ` TypeError: create_parser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parent'`.
Funnel's dependency coaster has a hard requirement for Flask-Script 0.5.3 so it's puzzling why the newer version is getting installed.